# Rewrite methods with generic with interface type Bound and implicit

Tags: java, scala, generics, implicit, scala-java-interop

I have a trait with generic and two alternative methods for checking age and name of employee.

```
trait Conditions[T] {
    def nameIs(color: String): T
    def ageUpperThan(upper: Int): T
}

def nameIs[T](color: String)(implicit fi: Conditions[T]): T = fi.nameIs(color)
```

I want to rewrite all these Scala code to Java which let me generate a concrete conditions for example to check the name is John.

```
def isJohn[T: Conditions]: T = nameIs[T]("John")
```

Also code have to show the result:

```
def show: Conditions[String] =
    new Conditions[String] {
        def nameIs(name: String): String = s"name is $name"
        def ageUpperThan(age: Int): String = s"age upper $age"
    }

println(isJohn[String](show))
```

Could yo help me to rewrite the methods nameIs and isJohn?

I have a problem with `implicit` and `[T: Conditions]`

Comment: What code have you attempted?  In Java, generics are not reifiable so that might give you issues.

Comment: You want to rewrite in Java? Isn't that the wrong direction? Do you mean you want to rewrite call sites like `isJohn` where the implicit is supplied by the compiler? That sounds like a high bar.